# rsync stuck in infinite loop trying to copy folder named nothing ()

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, infinite-loop

So here's an interesting problem I've stumbled upon.

I've been tasked with creating versioned backups with our huge file directory that we have, and so I am using a tool called "rsnapshot" which uses rsync to copy a directory and keep multiple versions of the same file, and it is working quite great, except for this one snag.

I'm not even entirely sure how this happened, but in one of our sub directories, there is a folder where the name is just a dot, I think. In Windows 10 the folder appears to be a dot, but if I paste it anywhere, it looks like this "".

It also appears that maybe rsync is treating this like a dot also, and so it copies the directory into itself infinitely, once it gets to this folder, all I see in there terminal is an ever growing number of slashes at the end of the directory.

What in the world is this and how do I stop/skip this weird folder thing?

**EDIT**

If I paste this character into HXD Hex Editor, it just pastes as a null byte, could just a single bull byte be this folder's name?

**EDIT 2**

So it looks like this folder's name is either a single NULL byte or is completely empty, and the bullet point that I see is just how Windows is displaying it. If I `ls` the directory in a Debian terminal, the file name shows up as a slash instead. I did try pasting the character into the rsync exclusions list I have set up (I was hopeful) but that definitely did not fix the problem.

**EDIT 3**

I have pictures! So this picture is from the Windows 10 Explorer

[image: Windows 10 Explorer]

And this picture is the output from the terminal on Debian

[image: Debian Terminal]

I see with some other research that this may just be a corrupt folder name, but that said it still is stopping me from backing this up, and even if I fix this once instance, there's no telling how many other files or folders will be like this, so it would definitely be best if I could somehow get rsync to either skip the file or do something at least a bit sane.

Comment: (Not an answer, just a data point which may/may not be relevant) - most OS's have a filesystem where "." means current directory and ".." means parent directory.  I don't know why rsync would be looking to back this up, but it would seem like some kind of conflict/corruption. "/" of-course, means the root of the filesystem.    If I were desperate, and willing to risk data loss, I might fire up midnight commander and use it to rename the directory.

Comment: Yeah I know the `.` and `..` and slash thing, but in this case I think are merely just how the different OS's are showing the absence of a real name, I'll have to post screenshots to really show what I mean I think

Comment: @davidgo I've added some images, hopefully that will aid in what I'm experiencing